# R - Running multiple scripts in parallel

Tags: r, performance, optimization, parallel-processing

I have 3 R scripts which take a lot of time to run. These scripts run each different data. I would like to run them in parallel. One solution is to run them in 3 different R sessions or 3 different projects as mentionned [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200526207-Using-Projects) or in 3 different batch. The problem is that I need to gather the data returned by these 3 scripts once they have run and complete the rest of computation in a fourth script that takes a lot of time as well. It would need to be done under Windows.

1. Is it possible to run these 3 scripts in parallel and return the ouput in one workspace to complete the computation with the fourth automatically? If yes, how?
2. Let's suppose that the answer to question 1 is yes. The fourth script output 3 variables. Is it possible to use them as input to the 3 scripts and loop until a condition in the 4th script is verified?

As an example you can assume the following scripts:

```
Script1.R   
Sys.sleep(10)  
a <- 3 

Script2.R  
Sys.sleep(10)  
b <- 5 

Script3.R  
Sys.sleep(10)  
c <- 56
```

In reality my scripts take 1 hour each to run. I would need to run the 3 above scripts in parallel, retrieve the 3 outputs a,b and c in the same workspace to continue the computation. So instead of having to wait 10 seconds for each scripts to compute I would wait only 10 seconds for the 3 scripts to compute. Alternatively you can take any 3 scripts of your choice that takes a lot of time to compute.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: Put it in your question please.

Comment: Use `system()` with `wait = FALSE` to trigger each script in its own R process and write the results to something like an RDS or RData file. Then have your main script run a while loop that periodically checks for the output files and, when all three are present, load them using `load()` or `readRDS()`.

Comment: @Thomas. Thank you for your answer. I think it answers the first question. How would you solve the second one?

Comment: depending on your OS you can use parallel packages like `foreach` to do this

Comment: https://beckmw.wordpress.com/2014/01/21/a-brief-foray-into-parallel-processing-with-r/

Answer (score 0):

Rstudio has a very reliable, easy and intuitive way of running parallel scripts called **Background jobs**. [This link](https://docs.posit.co/ide/user/ide/guide/tools/jobs.html) explains how to use it, but in summary, every time you run a script, it runs in parallel, using multiple cores and it usually goes much faster (if the CPU and RAM are not super busy). There are two ways to use Background Jobs, the manual and the scripted:

1. The manual way: you just open the *background job* and select the script and the working directory. Then, in your case, your script should save the objects at local, using [`saveRSD()`](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/saving-data-into-r-data-format-rds-and-rdata) or save multiple objects with `save()`. You can run the script three times (in your case), changing just the line with the object you want to use in each case, save the script and run background job, and then change again the script with the second value, save the script and run the background job again, etc. This way you can run it in parallel but please, check that CPU or RAM do not run at values too close to 100%. And please, do not name a variable/object with a 'c'...
2. The scripted way: you can use [JobRunScript](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudioapi/reference/jobRunScript.html) to create background jobs with code. Therefore you can automate the changes you want from the scripts.